# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API throwing an http error 401, despite Azure SSO token being validated

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-entra-id

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API being hit from a react front end.

I have configured both with the correct tenant, clientID, etc, and I can login to the react site fine, I get a token. I have looked at the JWT token and it looks fine.

However when I post to the Web API, I am getting back a http error 401 Unauthorized as a response. Looking at the output from the Web API, I see this debug output:

```
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter: Information: IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX10241: Security token validated. token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter: Information: IDX10241: Security token validated. token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
dbug: Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource.JwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnostics[0]
      Begin OnTokenValidatedAsync. 
Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource.JwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnostics: Debug: Begin OnTokenValidatedAsync. 
dbug: Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource.JwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnostics[0]
      End OnTokenValidatedAsync.
```

It appears as though the token is validated, but the Web API is still returning a http 401.

I have seen some posts about issues occurring due to the order of calls to set up the app, but I believe I have

```
app.UseAthentication();
```

and

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

in the correct location / order.

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(
    MyAllowSpecificOrigins
);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is my react configuration values ("sanitized" values)

```
REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID=11111111-1111-1111-11111-111111111111
REACT_APP_AUTHORITY=<microsoftloginurl>/22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222
REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL=<localhost>:3000
REACT_APP_API_URL=<localhost>:7145/api
```

And the Web API ("sanitized" values")

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "<microsoftloginurl>",
    "Domain": "my.domain",
    "TenantId": "11111111-1111-1111-11111-111111111111",
    "ClientId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a role and assigned it to my user, and am no longer getting 401s. I had assumed that without setting up a role, any user token would be accepted in the post to the api, but that doesn't look like the case.